# Windows 8: How to disable touch in Flipview control?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Is it possible to disable the touch scrolling of a flipview?

For example you can disable a scrollviewers scroll mode by setting the HorizontalScrollMode to False

I just need to disable it temporarily so I can manipulate the canvas inside the flipview using touch gestures.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting hold of the ScrollViewer in the template of a FlipView using VisualTreeHelper and disable its scrolling.

Comment: Which specific properties must be changed to accomplish this? I'm trying several and haven't found any that work yet.

Comment: `HorizontalScrollMode`. Actually - you could probably set something like `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"` just on the `FlipView`. I think the control template might be binding that to the `ScrollViewer` inside.